# SLEEP_TASK Wait Type

Tags: sql-server

I have recently have an issue with the wait Type 'SLEEP_TASK', udder Idle category.

In my system it's the main wait type.

Do someone know what is it?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11800/sleep-task-wait-type-in-sql-server-what-does-it-indicate)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SLEEP_TASK means that scheduler is waiting something to happen (which doesn't mean that it's bad thing),if you are collecting wait stats there are some waits which you probably want to filter out in many cases,and SLEEP_TASK is one of them.What are other wait types that you have on server ?

There is [Paul White's great answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11800/sleep-task-wait-type-in-sql-server-what-does-it-indicate) on that question.

Comment: Does it include tempdb issues?

Answer (score 0):

"The situation [...] is always a situation where the SQL Server is waiting for the next command from the client."

I found this answer here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2008/04/21/how-it-works-what-is-a-sleeping-awaiting-command-session/